# Moving away from main thread and returning data to Activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

What is the best way to move away from UI thread in Activity when you need to perform one task at a time. Also return data to activity. Consider activity can be paused, stopped or destroyed?

1) HandlerThread

2) RxAndroid

3) Loader

4) AsyncTask

5) RoboSpice

6) ThreadPoolExecuter

7) EventBus

8) Or Something Else

Thanks.

Sorry for this very basic question. I have read few articles they made me confuse. I usually use AsyncTask and thought that loader was the next step but now I have no idea.

Comment: its not something to say for sure but I myself use RXjava its a bit harder to use but it will have minimum memory leaks and gives you more control over your callbacks.

Comment: I am facing this problem more and more and I read in many articles AsyncTask is not the right way. I am read to learn any thing if that worth it.

Comment: @AmirZiarati  Did you ever used Loader. Tell me is I Rxjava will it cover the cases of loaders.

Comment: if you ask me learn RXjava cause its the newest and the best one. no i didnt use loader.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything  , All were designed for multithreading , 
Each one has unique functionality which covers a specific use case

For examples , Handlers has Message queues , where you can process many messages(threads)

Loaders Persist even after orientation Changes (activities dont)

AysncTask is used for Short , quick operations like hitting a webservice.
Its upto you to decide what  you actually use

Based on your case, (returning data to activity,  Loader will be suitable)

Comment: If I have to choice between Loader and RxJava then?

Comment: Rx Java is events based ,(if something happens perform this) , it can be used for any events like clicks, view inflated , letter entered , app closed etc ,  Loaders create a loader (typically like cursor ) and monitor the data source . it has its own callback

Comment: AsyncTask is error prone what if the call came,alarm start ring or user switch to another app. I think this can happen even with short task.

Comment: yes it can be , But this could be overcome when returning the result from aysnc Task , check whether activity is destroyed or not (or any other references like imageview or textview)

Comment: By keeping reference of activity or its views can cause memory leaks. http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/

Comment: Yes you are Right but there is concept called Weak reference in Java that lets you object be garbage collected  Besides that, if you want to your code to be So production Ready , you should read read through every concepts documentation thoroughly . My suggestion is "We learn Best through Actions" , implement something and if error occurs , rectify it,   you cannot learn all the things, by the time you learn , you will not have you hair. Implement and Iterate the concepts you already know.

Comment: That is why I had ask above question from more experience developer like you so I do not have to make the same mistakes they did. Plus may be help from developer like you I may have left with few more hairs.Thank Man!!!